# Map seems to drop values in recursion

Tags: go, maps, logic

I've been working on a problem and I figured I would demonstrate it using a pokemon setup. I am reading from a file, parsing the file and creating objects/structs from them. This normally isn't a problem except now I need to implement interface like inheriting of traits. I don't want there to be duplicate skills in there so I figured I could use a map to replicate a set data structure. However it seems that in the transitive phase of my recursive parsePokemonFile function (see the implementsComponent case), I appear to be losing values in my map.

I am using the inputs like such:

4 files

Ratatta:

```
name=Ratatta
skills=Tackle:normal,Scratch:normal
```

Bulbosaur:

```
name=Bulbosaur
implements=Ratatta
skills=VineWhip:leaf
```

Oddish:

```
name=Oddish
implements=Ratatatt
skills=Acid:poison
```

Venosaur:

```
name=Venosaur
implements=bulbosaur,oddish
```

I'm expecting the output for the following code to be something like

```
Begin!
{Venosaur [{VineWhip leaf} {Acid poison} {Tackle normal} {Scratch normal}]}
```

but instead I get

```
Begin!
{Venosaur [{VineWhip leaf} {Acid poison}]}
```

What am I doing wrong? Could it be a logic error? Or am I making an assumption about the map holding values that I shouldn't?

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

// In order to create a set of pokemon abilities and for ease of creation and lack of space being taken up
// We create an interfacer capability that imports the skills and attacks from pokemon of their previous evolution
// This reduces the amount of typing of skills we have to do.
// Algorithm is simple. Look for the name "implements=x" and then add x into set.
// Unfortunately it appears that the set is dropping values on transitive implements interfaces

func main() {
     fmt.Println("Begin!")
    dex, err := parsePokemonFile("Venosaur")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Got error: %v\n", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", dex)
}

type pokemon struct {
    Name   string
    Skills []skill
}

type skill struct {
    SkillName string
    Type      string
}

func parsePokemonFile(filename string) (pokemon, error) {
    file, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return pokemon{}, err
    }
    defer file.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    var builtPokemon pokemon
    for scanner.Scan() {
        component, returned := parseLine(scanner.Text())
        switch component {
        case nameComponent:
            builtPokemon.Name = returned
        case skillsComponent:
            skillsStrings := strings.Split(returned, ",")
            var skillsArr []skill
            // split skills and add them into pokemon skillset
            for _, skillStr := range skillsStrings {
                skillPair := strings.Split(skillStr, ":")
                skillsArr = append(skillsArr, skill{SkillName: skillPair[0], Type: skillPair[1]})
            }
            builtPokemon.Skills = append(builtPokemon.Skills, skillsArr...)
        case implementsComponent:
            implementsArr := strings.Split(returned, ",")
            // create set to remove duplicates
            skillsSet := make(map[*skill]bool)
            for _, val := range implementsArr {
                // recursively call the pokemon files and get full pokemon
                implementedPokemon, err := parsePokemonFile(val)
                if err != nil {
                    return pokemon{}, err
                }
                // sieve out the skills into a set
                for _, skill := range implementedPokemon.Skills {
                    skillsSet[&skill] = true
                }
            }
            // append final set into the currently being built pokemon
            for x := range skillsSet {
                builtPokemon.Skills = append(builtPokemon.Skills, *x)
            }
        }
    }
    return builtPokemon, nil
}

type component int

// components to denote where to put our strings when it comes time to assemble what we've parsed
const (
    nameComponent component = iota
    implementsComponent
    skillsComponent
)

func parseLine(line string) (component, string) {
    arr := strings.Split(line, "=")
    switch arr[0] {
    case "name":
        return nameComponent, arr[1]
    case "implements":
        return implementsComponent, arr[1]
    case "skills":
        return skillsComponent, arr[1]
    default:
        panic("Invalid field found")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Golang maps dropping any values.

The problem is that you are using a map of skill pointers and not skills. Two pointers to the same skill content can be different.

> `skillsSet := make(map[*skill]bool)`

If you change this to `map[skill]bool`, this should work. You may try it out!

Comment: In Go pointers are valid key types for maps, while your suggestion may or may not fix OP's issue, claiming that the use of pointers as keys causes the problem is just inaccurate.

Comment: In Go, you cannot have a non pointer struct as a key in a Go map. I've tried. The compiler complains.

Comment: @RichardJohnCatalano that's incorrect, non-pointer structs are valid key types: https://play.golang.com/p/c9MQTFrzLoU

Comment: @mkopriva I never claimed that pointers are not valid key types for maps. They are being wrongly used in the example and I suggested an alternative which could solve the problem.

Comment: @mkopriva That's so strange...it's allowing me to now but I swear it wasn't letting me before on the problem that I based this example off of. Either way switching to a non pointer for some reason solves this. Must have something to do with the copies getting tangled and dropped?

Comment: Could there be a problem if I were to use an exported struct type as a key in the map?

Comment: @RichardJohnCatalano The reason is known. You are using the map to remove duplicates. Pointers to the same skill content can be different and thus the strange behavior you are seeing!!

Comment: @RichardJohnCatalano Nope, there is no problem with that, it will still work.

Comment: @RichardJohnCatalano you can use structs as long as all of the members of the struct are comparable https://play.golang.com/p/yHQfhgiGO8E

Comment: So if they contain slices of embedded structs, would that make them no longer comparable?

Comment: @RichardJohnCatalano correct, https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators `Slice, map, and function values are not comparable.` So a struct type that has one or more fields of those types cannot be used as a key in a map.

Comment: Ahhhh...in that case, what would you recommend for how I go about it?

Comment: @RichardJohnCatalano well in your example `skill` is a string so its hard to tell. Is skill in the actual code a struct?

Comment: in the actual code this was based on skill is a struct containing a string and two slices of structs for which in each struct contain two strings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190388/discussion-between-richard-john-catalano-and-mkopriva).